# Alternative formula for centrifugal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors, centrifugal-force

The centrifugal force has the formula
$$ f_C=\Omega^2r $$ and vectored
$$ \vec{f_C}=\vec{\Omega} \times(\vec{\Omega}\times \vec{r}) $$
However there is also the known formula
$$ f_C=\frac{v^2}{r} $$
Is there a vectored formula for the second form?

Comment: you assumed circle motion, otherwise is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as:

$$\overrightarrow{f_C} = \frac{v^2}{r^2} \overrightarrow{r}$$

Where the center of rotation is the origin.

Comment: Unless $\vec{r}$ is defined in an usual way, there shouldn't be any minus sign. The centrifugal force, as the name implies, is oriented from the center of rotation to the outside, as is $\vec{r}$.

Comment: I have edited to correct it

Answer (score 0):

You can use $|\vec\Omega| = v/r$, which shows you that the vector formula and the scalar one are equal in the sense that
$$|\vec f_C| = f_C$$
if we have
$$\vec r \perp \vec\Omega$$, which is typically the case.

Comment: I need the vectored form of f_C. Scalar cannot be used

Comment: well you can just use $\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|^3}\vec v \times (\vec v \times \vec r)$, if that helps you.

Basically you can construct it however you like, you just need smth with diretion in $\vec r$ and magnitude $\frac{v^2}{r}$, so e.g. $\frac{v^2}{r^2} \vec r$ would also work.

Comment: Ah thanks I will try this out